# How can I implement a monadic interface (map, flatMap) for a type R[Out] { type In }?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What I want to do is to implement a reader monad `R[Out] { type In }` that reads some value of type `Out` (type parameter, or generic type) from abstract input `In` (abstract type member). It's typically may be viewed as `R[In, Out]`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
trait R[+Out] { self =>
  type In

  def apply(in: In): Out

  def map[Out2](f: Out => Out2): R[Out2] = new R[Out2] {
    type In = self.In
    def apply(in: In): Out2 = f(self(in))
  }

  def flatMap[Out2](f: Out => R[Out2] { type In = self.In }): R[Out2] = 
    new R[Out2] {
      type In = self.In
      def apply(in: In): Out2 = f(self(in))(in)
    }
}

def foo[I, O](o: O): R[O] = new R[O] {
  type In = I
  def apply(in: I): O = o
}

//
// compiles
//
val a: R[String] = foo[Int, String]("b").map(_ + "a")

// does not compile
//
//  <console>:45: error: type mismatch;
//   found   : R[String]
//   required: R[String]{type In = a.In}
//
val b: R[String] = a.flatMap(x => foo[Int, String](x))
```

What should I do to makes this work? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem is that some of your methods like `foo` return `R[O]`, and not `R[O] { type In  = I }`. It compiles, but it's `apply` method is broken in the sense that we don't know that the inner type alias is `Int`, and instead the compiler sees `f.In`, so it doesn't know that it should allow passing an `Int`:

```
scala> val f = foo[Int, String]("2")
f: R[String] = $anon$1@3cbccfc1

scala> f(2)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: f.In
              f(2)
                ^
```

You can fix this by fixing the return type:

```
def foo[I, O](o: O): R[O] { type In = I } = new R[O] {
  type In = I
  def apply(in: I): O = o
}

scala> val f = foo[Int, String]("2")
f: R[String]{type In = Int} = $anon$1@d9f9598

scala> f(2)
res20: String = 2  // It works!
```

Similarly, your `map` and `flatMap` return `R[Out2]` instead of `R[Out2] { type In = self.In }`. Leaving out the the refinement `{ type In = self.In }` is akin to leaving out the type parameter `I` in `R[I, O]`. Without it,  the compiler doesn't know that an `R[String]` has a `type In = Int`, even if it seems painfully obvious from the code. You could also compare it to up-casting the returned value, where you lose some of the type information that could have otherwise been guaranteed by using a more accurate type.

Putting it all together:

```
trait R[+Out] { self =>
  type In

  def apply(in: In): Out

  def map[Out2](f: Out => Out2): R[Out2] { type In = self.In } = new R[Out2] {
    type In = self.In
    def apply(in: In): Out2 = f(self(in))
  }

  def flatMap[Out2](f: Out => R[Out2] { type In = self.In }): R[Out2] { type In = self.In } = 
    new R[Out2] {
      type In = self.In
      def apply(in: In): Out2 = f(self(in))(in)
    }
}

def foo[I, O](o: O): R[O] { type In = I } = new R[O] {
  type In = I
  def apply(in: I): O = o
}

// At this point I just started relying on type inference to avoid
// continuing this notation.

scala> val a = foo[Int, String]("b").map(_ + "a")
a: R[String]{type In = Int} = R$$anon$1@4be408f0

scala> val b = a.flatMap(x => foo[Int, String](x))
b: R[String]{type In = a.In} = R$$anon$2@19fa8e56
```

Comment: This is cool! Thanks! Do you think this is possible to use something like R[A] instead of R[A] { type In = XX } for cases when types should be written explicitly? Like `val a: RR[String] = foo[Int, String]("a")`.

Comment: @VladimirKostyukov I don't think so, because you lose the type information.